# Siemens sim2k-34vr ecu parametrs and service ids

Tags: obd-ii, electronic-control-module, diagnostics, obd

I need to read parametres like RPM of the engine from siemens sim2k-34vr ECU from obd2 port through K-line protocol,I tried standard service id `0x01` to read current data but ECU said `0x01` service id is not defined, Is there any documentation to find service ids of Siemens ECU?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found its `PIDS` is under `MODE` 0x21 and `PID` 0x01, I hope it helps to other peoples.